# OpenCL instantiating local memory array: invalid pointer error in kernel

Tags: c++, opencl

I'm trying to create 2 local arrays for a kernel to use.  My goal is to copy a global input buffer into the first array (arr1), and instantiate the second array (arr2) so its elements can be accessed and set later.

My kernel looks like this:

```
__kernel void do_things (__global uchar* in, __global uchar* out, 
uint numIterations, __local uchar* arr1, __local uchar* arr2)
{
  size_t work_size = get_global_size(0) * get_global_size(1);

  event_t event;
  async_work_group_copy(arr1, in, work_size, event);
  wait_group_events(1, &event);

  int cIndex = (get_global_id(0) * get_global_size(1)) + get_global_id(1);
  arr2[cIndex] = 0;

  //Do other stuff later
}
```

In the C++ code I'm calling this from, I set the kernel arguments like this:

```
//Create input and output buffers
cl_mem inputBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY |
    CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, myInputVector.size(), (void*) 
    myInputVector.data(), NULL);
cl_mem outputBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,
    myInputVector.size(), NULL, NULL);

//Set kernel arguments.
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&inputBuffer));
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&outputBuffer));
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_uint), &iterations));
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 3, sizeof(inputBuffer), NULL));
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 4, sizeof(inputBuffer), NULL));
```

Where myInputVector is a vector full of uchars.

Then, I enqueue it with a 2D work size, rows * cols big.  myInputVector has a size of rows * cols.

```
//Execute the kernel
size_t global_work_size[2] = { rows, cols }; //2d work size
status = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue, kernel, 2, NULL,
    global_work_size, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

The problem is, I'm getting crashes when I run the kernel.  Specifically, this line in the kernel:

```
arr2[cIndex] = 0;
```

is responsible for the crash (omitting it makes it so it doesn't crash anymore).  The error reads:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./MyProgram: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000001a28fb0 ***
```

All I want is to be able to access arr2 alongside arr1.  arr2 should be the same size as arr1.  If that's the case, **Why am I getting this bizarre error?  Why is this an invalid pointer?**

Comment: how `inputBuffer` is defined?

Comment: it's created right up there:  cl_mem inputBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY |
    CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, myInputVector.size(), (void*) 
    myInputVector.data(), NULL);

Comment: sorry, I meant `myInputVector`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are allocating only `sizeof(cl_mem)` for your local buffers. And a `cl_mem` is simply a typedef of some sort of pointer type (therefore 4 to 8 bytes depending on your system).

What then happen in your kernel is that you are accessing beyond the size of the local buffer you allocated and the GPU launches a memory fault.

```
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 3, myInputVector.size(), NULL);
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 4, myInputVector.size(), NULL);
```

Should fix your problem. Also note that the size you are providing is the size in bytes so you would need to multiply by the `sizeof` of the vector element type (which is not clear from code).